# Why won't my model save to Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm quite new to Objective-C and I'm trying to mess around with Core Data. I have the following App Delegate interface and implementation:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SDTAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveManagedObjectContext;
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)setupManagedObjectContext;
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)setupManagedObjectModel;
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)setupPersistentStoreCoordinator;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "SDTAppDelegate.h"
#import "ToDoItem.h"

@implementation SDTAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Get the managed object context and associate it to the app delegate
    self.managedObjectContext = [self setupManagedObjectContext];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self saveManagedObjectContext];
}

/**
 * Save the MOC!
 */
- (void)saveManagedObjectContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    if (self.managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            /*
             THIS NEEDS TO BE REPLACED
             */
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

/**
 Returns the managed object context for the application.
 If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)setupManagedObjectContext
{
    if (self.managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        return self.managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self setupPersistentStoreCoordinator];

    if (coordinator != nil)
    {
        self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [self.managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }

    return self.managedObjectContext;
}

/**
 * Return the managed object model. If it doesn't exist, create it.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)setupManagedObjectModel
{
    if (self.managedObjectModel != nil)
    {
        return self.managedObjectModel;
    }

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];

    self.managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    return self.managedObjectModel;
}

/**
 * Return the persistent store coordinator. If it doesn't exist, create it.
 */
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)setupPersistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (self.persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Model.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    self.persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self setupManagedObjectModel]];

    if (![self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                       configuration:nil
                                                                 URL:storeURL
                                                             options:nil
                                                               error:&error])
    {
        /*
         THIS NEEDS TO BE REPLACED
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

/**
 * Return the URL to the application's Documents directory.
 */
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

@end
```

And then in my controller I have the following to save a new model:

```
// Take the managed object context from the app delegate
SDTAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SDTAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

// Add the new item
ToDoItem *newItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ToDoItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];
newItem.item = self.textField.text;
newItem.completed = 0;
```

No matter what happens I can't get the application to save. It shows up fine in the interface, but when I quit and restart the data is no longer there. I'm guessing this is something wrong with my persistent storage?

Comment: When do you actually call ``saveManagedObjectContext`` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save the context in order to save in the persistent store.

```
NSError *error;
[context save:&error];
```

Hope it helps. Cheers

Comment: that did work. Thanks! Can you explain what's happening here? Do I always have to save after each new entity.. I thought the point of Core Data was that it auto saved?

Comment: If you don't save the context the entity is not saved in the persistent store, thereby it exists only in memory. Saving depends on your scenario, you could save when the app goes in background, you could save on app's exit or after every change or for example in batches if you're importing a large data set. It really depends on your scenario.

Comment: oh okay, so saving in applicationWillTerminate still doesn't count as context? It has to be saved in the class where the context is being updated?

Comment: Saving a NSManagedObject (into the ManagedObjectContext) is typically not an expensive operation. I usually save after any significant changes.